# Enable a process started from a service in Accessibility on Mac

Tags: macos, service, accessibility

My bundle structure is like below:

- A helper tool
- A service
- An UI
- A console binary

The workflow is when users open the UI the first time, it will install the helper tool which would, in turn, install the service by copying the plist file into the ~/Library/LaunchAgent directory and call launchctl command. Then the UI will prompt users to enable the bundle in the accessibility tab. The job of the service is to monitoring and spawning the console binary which requires accessibility to work.

All the components are in the same bundle and code signed. The bundle structure looks like this:

App/Contents/Library/LaunchService/helper

App/Contents/MacOS/service

App/Contents/MacOS/ui

App/Contents/MacOS/console

The issue is even when users enable the whole bundle in accessibility, the console is started by the service at the background, but the console still fails when it checks if itself is a trusted accessibility client. I'm using the Mac API, AXIsProcessTrusted, to do the checking.

I'm not sure if the workflow has a flaw or the AXIsProcessTrusted API call is not what I want.